# The type of auto variable when assign its value from a function whose return value is reference

Tags: c++, reference, auto

Check following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    long *context;
public:
    A(long i)
    {
        context = new long;
        *context = i;
    }

    long& getContext()
    {
        return *context;
    }
};

A a(1234);

int main(void)
{
    auto v = a.getContext();
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The return value of `A::getContext()` is reference, and the type of `auto` variable `v` is `long`, not `long&`:

```
....
auto v = a.getContext();
....
```

What're the defects if `v`'s type is reference?

Comment: Huh? There's no defect. The rules for deducing `auto` prefer value types. You are defining an object, after all.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why `context` being a pointer? Even if it was a structure in your "real" code, there's seldom any need to make it a pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Just a simple example to demonstrate issue.

Comment: Well you don't need a pointer for that, really.

Comment: Could you please take the time to clarify your question? `v` isn't a reference, so it isn't clear to me what are you asking about.

Comment: @StoryTeller I just wonder in "`auto v = a.getContext();`", why `v`'s type is `long`, not `long&`. Is there any consideration for compiler to do this behavior? Thx!

Comment: There it has a duplicate. Please read it.